# Is there any difference between selecting knife tool in the tool menu and pressing hotkey "K"?

Tags: 2d, knife-tool

So I have been trying to use the knife tool, and I want to start my cut on an exsisting vertex.

I noticed that if I click knife tool in the tool menu, I get a knife cursor, and I cannot start cutting on an exsisting vertex -- I will always creat a new vertex no matter how hard I try to place my first cut near an exsisting one.

On the other hand, if I just press K, I magically get a knife with a tiny block beneath it, and I can select an exisiting vertex for a start now. How come that the hot key functions differently from the toolmenu option itself? I must have missed some feature of knife, right?

[image: knife from toolmenu]
[image: knife from hotkey]

Comment: Hi :). Probably an oversight from developers. Hotkeys should give you the exact same behaviors as the toolbar.

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I was thinking. Wouldn't it be easier to just, idk, use the same api for these two operations?

Comment: True. There are some lingering inconsistencies... a price for the rapid development i guess :))

Answer (score 5):

### It is difference between you use shortcut and call it in menu.

In the Preferences, You can see there has two same operator `mesh.knife_tool`
`K` and `shift` `K` which has difference settings. That will have difference behaviors. Also you can add more shortcut to this operator and do difference behaviors.

[image]

#### The knife tool in Tool menu and the shortcut K is two difference operator

knife tool:

```
wm.tool_set_by_id
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, that was something new to me. Yet still I am confused. Say, if I want to call knife tool from toolmenu instead of  pressing "K", and I want to start my cut from an exsisting vertex, what do I do?

Comment: Today, you cannot change the Toolmenu default setting except you modify the source code

Comment: Alright, I guess that's as far as I can go now. I'll look into it and see what I can get. Thank you for your time!

Comment: To use the tool to snap to a vertex, simply hover near the vertex and left click to select that vertex as a starting point.